# Entity Framework Include/select only certain properties from different tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

Let's say I have a method called `GetThreadWithComments()`. Each thread has 1 user (the creator) and has a list of comments. Each comments has 1 user (the poster).

Here are the classes (generated by EF):

```
public class Thread
{
    public int ThreadId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public long CommentId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ThreadId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

So basically, I want to load a thread with user info, and associated comments with user info. I've tried something like this:

```
db.Threads.Select(x => new
{
    x,
    x.User = new { x.User.Username, x.User.Email },
    x.Comments = x.Comments.Select(c => new
    {
        c.Message,
        c.CommentId,
        c.User = new { c.User.Username, c.User.Email }
    })
});
```

The above does not work. However, I am not too sure on how to correctly do this. I could use `include`, but that would generate all properties. Since speed is a concern, I am trying to keep things as light as possible.

Reason it does not work: it does not build. Compile time error. The 2 errors I get are:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '' to...

and

> CS0746 Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: Why does *the above does not work* ? Any errors or something? As far as i know entity relationships must be declared as `virtual`, so `public User User { get; set; }` should be `public virtual User User { get; set; }` right?

Comment: if you don't rectify this comment `The above does not work.` im down voting and flagging to close. Why doesn't it work, does your computer turn off, did your dog eat it, was there a singularity created?

Comment: I think question is clear. @ViRuSTriNiTy

Comment: I will edit my answer soon lol. Updated. I noticed the downvote and flag to close. Can you please calm down, I was away for few minutes. @MichaelRandall

Comment: @FerX32 revoked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define entity relationships as `virtual`, for example

```
public User User { get; set; }
```

should be

```
public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

Second, in case of the later posted compiler error, try adding the member names.

So instead of

`x.User = new { x.User.Username, x.User.Email }`

use

`x.User = new { Username = x.User.Username, Email = x.User.Email }`

Also there is too much `x` in there. The corrected example would be:

```
db.Threads.Select(x => new
{
    x,
    User = new { Username = x.User.Username, Email = x.User.Email },
    Comments = x.Comments.Select(c => new
    {
        c.Message,
        c.CommentId,
        User = new { Username = c.User.Username, Email = c.User.Email }
    })
});
```

Comment: It built, the compile errors are gone. I will test it out tomorrow since it's 3 AM here. Thank you so much for the help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var result = db.Threads.Include(thread => thread.Comments);
```

Hope helps,

Comment: Didn't he write  `I could use include, but` ...?

Comment: That's right. Include will generate all properties for Comments. I only wanted few properties. E.g. CommentID, and Message.

Comment: It wont load until you select. @ViRuSTriNiTy